# Can session.getAttribute extend the maxInteractiveInterval of session or prevent the attribute from disappearing?

Tags: spring, session

I'm working on a spring web toy project.

I use the session attribute to store random member IDs and confirm whether logged in or not on the spring interceptor using that information.

However, I realized that the information I stored during the login process are lost after being redirected to another page.

After several debugging trials, I figure out that the attribute is alive in the interceptor but is lost after posthandle method is finished.

The really strange thing is that when I put the code to look up the attributes in the interceptor, the attributes don't disappear and all the functions work normally. But information is gone after I erase these codes.

HomeRenderInterceptor.java (prehandle, posthandle methods)

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    beforeHome(request);

    /*==========below is the weird debugging code i mentioned above===========*/
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    Long memberId = (Long) session.getAttribute("memberId");
    System.out.println(memberId);
    /*========================================================================*/
    return true;
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    beforeHome(request);
}
```

It's good that the function works normally, but I couldn't understand at all why one debugging code determines the survival of the attribute.

If you know the cause or have a different perspective on this problem, I would like to get a hint so that I can find it and study it more.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question.
I didn't figure out how adding some debugging code solved my problem temporarily.
But I noticed that my other interceptor's excludePathPattern didn't work well.
So I used addPathPattern only, deleted debugging code, run my application again. Then it worked well.